# Neovim Indent Bug?

Tags: vim, neovim

I have the following options in my `.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set ai
set smartindent
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

So, the indentation engine should work on all files, but it does not.
When I edit my config file for example, `:set ai` returns: `autoindent` and `:set si` returns: `smartindent`. 
But when I run the same commands on a php file they return:

```
noautoindent
nosmartindent
```

EDIT:
The file that was overriding my config is:
`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/indent/php.vim`
It's the default php indent file.

Comment: you probably have a php plugin right?. This plugin overwrites your settings (you can debug it with `:verbose set ai?`). A short hint which could help you is to have a look at `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`

Comment: You are right, thanks. I've found that the standard nvim php indent has the noautoindent and nosmartindent set. The problem is that I usually edit .phtml files, so I would need a special indent config. Thanks.

Comment: as mention, you can put your config in the `after/ftplugin` folder to overwrite the nvim php indent. Or you could also handle phtml and php differently.